# Can I bind a parameter to a PDO statement as a comparison operator?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, code-injection, parameterized-query

Is this code

```
class opinion
{
   private $dbh;
   var $opinionid,$opinion,$note,$actorid,$dateposted;
   var $isnew=FALSE;
   function loadby($column,$value,$operator="="){
       $dbh = new PDO(I deleted parameters here);
       $statement=$dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion where :column :operator :value");
       $statement->bindParam(":column", $column);
       $statement->bindParam(":value", $value);
       $statement->bindParam(":operator", $operator); //UNSURE, DOUBTFUL
       $statement->bindColumn("opinionid", $this->opinionid);
       $statement->bindColumn("opinion", $this->opinion);
       $statement->bindColumn("note", $this->note);
       $statement->bindColumn("actorid", $this->actorid);
       $statement->bindColumn("dateposted", $this->dateposted);
       $statement->fetch();
       return $statement->rowCount(); //please be 1
   }
}
```

injection safe?

```
       $statement->bindParam(":operator", $operator); //UNSURE, DOUBTFUL
```

Can I bind a parameter to a PDO statement as a comparison operator?

Comment: Never seen this done before, I suspect that it will try to escape the operator which would result in `'column' '=' 'value';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot bind operators like that. As a workaround, you can dynamically create the "base" SQL query and use an operator whitelist (which is quite appropriate) to remain safe from injection:

```
function loadby($column,$value,$operator="="){ 
   $dbh = new PDO(...); 
   $operator = getOperator($operator);
   if(!$operator) {
       // error handling
   }
   $statement=$dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion where :column $operator :value");
   // the rest like you already do it
} 

function getOperator($operator) {
   $allowed_ops = array('=', '<', '>'); // etc
   return in_array($operator, $allowed_ops) ? $operator : false;
}
```

Apart from this, the rest is fine and injection-proof "by definition".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment I don't think it's possible to escape the operator and have it work as you expect. The resulting query would probably look something like:

```
'column' '=' 'value';
```

You don't need to escape the operator to avoid injection attacks,  you can validate your operator before appending it to the string, consider:

```
class opinion
{
    $validOperators = array('=', '>=', '>', '=<', '<');

    function loadby($column,$value,$operator="=") {

        // Validate operator
        if (!in_array($operator, self::$validOperators)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid $operator ' . $operator . ')';
        }

        $statement=$dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion where :column " . $operator . " :value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the DBMS and PHP driver, prepared statements can be "real" or emulated.

In the first case, bind parameters are handled directly by the DBMS. In such case, handling an operator as parameter will probably trigger a syntax error. The SQL parser will analyse the query without even looking at parameters and will not find valid SQL code to work on.

In the second case, bind parameters are emulated by the driver: input values get inserted into SQL code (with adequate escaping) and the DBMS receives a complete regular query. I'm not really sure about how current drivers will behave (I'd need to test it) but even if they don't complain about invalid SQL, they'll hit a wall sooner or later: SQL operators are not strings.

Now, would it be a nice feature to get implemented some day? I doubt it is:

- You won't benefit from pre-parsed SQL when running repetitive queries: if you change operators, you change the query.
- You won't get *safe* SQL code. How could you?

Comment: I used $statement=$dbh->prepare("select * from fe_opinion where :column $operator :value"); //$operator instead of binding. $operator is safe because I will use it in the code, it wont be an user input.

Answer (score -2):

You can actually do it. The sql just gets more complicated. Depending on the number of combinations, the sql can get really huge. But, sometimes when there's only a few choices, its nice.

```
select * 
  from someTable

where (case :column
       when 'age' then (case :operator
                               when '>' then age > :value
                               when '<' then age < :value
                        end)
       when 'price' then (case :operator
                               when '>' then price > :value
                               when '<' then price < :value
                        end)
      end)

  and someOtherCol = 'foo'
```

The :value could be another column too, but you'll need to nest yet again another case construct like for the first column, and the combinations are really soaring now.

Anyway... just wanted to show it can be done.

Comment: that could be useful for stored procedures. Jon demonstrated a practical solution. Thanks anyway.