# Laravel Query Builder does not run query correctly even thought it binds correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a problem with the Laravel Query Builder. When I try to bind a variable, which would include some sort of sql code, into my binding parameter, it returns no results. If I run enableQueryLog() I can see that the query and the binding is correct. So the code provides a perfectly fine query but yet it does not perform accordingly.

I've already tried printing out all the variables that matter. I enabled a query log to see if everything is set correctly, which it is. When I put in the variable in my whereRaw() just as it is without binding, it works fine. Just not with the binding.

This is the code I run:

```
public function getCarbrands() {

        $name = 'name != Ford';
        try {
            $brands = DB::table('ni_carbrands')
                ->whereRaw(':name',['name'=>$name])
                ->select('id','name')
                ->get();
            echo json_encode( array('info' => 1 ,'status' => 'Successfully found car brands', 'details' => $brands));

        } catch(Exception $e){

            echo json_encode( array('info' => 0 ,'status' => 'Error finding car brands', 'e' => $e)); 

        }

    }
```

I know that this use of the binding feature is unnecessary, it is merely a test for some other functions I wanna build. 
This is what my Query Log returns:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `id`, `name` from `ni_carbrands` where :name"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "name != Ford"
    ]
    "time" => 190.25
  ]
]
```

The components of the query all seem correct, but yet it seems to have some trouble producing it.

The expected results would be something like this:

```
{
    "info": 1,
    "status": "Successfully found car brands",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Toyota"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Fiat"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Iveco"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Citroën"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Opel"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Mercedes"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Volkswagen"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Renault"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "MAN"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Nissan"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Hyundai"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Peugeot"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the actual result is:

```
{"info":1,"status":"Successfully found car brands","details":[]}
```

I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: can you give the response code?? where you add this data to details??

Comment: Sorry, I put up the whole function now. The response code is the provided information on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you cant bind a string containing an operator.
Have a look into this one [Can I bind a parameter to a PDO statement as a comparison operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389928/can-i-bind-a-parameter-to-a-pdo-statement-as-a-comparison-operator)
And this one [binding not null in pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033961/binding-not-null-in-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

Bad raw condition:
`whereRaw(':name',['name'=>$name])`
Just like this:

```
$brands = DB::table('ni_carbrands')
                ->select('id','name')
                ->whereRaw($name)
                ->get();
```

Comment: I know that it works like this. I also stated this in my question. The thing is, I dont want it to work like that. And more importantly I want to know why it does not work the way I did it.

Comment: Bindings variable separated by a ```?``` mark. ```':name'``` where did you get that? variables are replaced as follows ```->whereRaw('?',['name'=>$name])```

Comment: I got it from the laravel docu and some posts on here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries
Also, I tried your method before and it also does not work.

Comment: The binding method I use also works, just not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can this use this kind of also

```
$brands = DB::table('ni_carbrands')
            ->select('id','name')
            ->where('name', '!=', 'Ford')
            ->get();
```

otherwise you can set where condition in dynamic field
like

```
->where($name, '!=', 'Ford')
```

Comment: As stated, I know that those versions work and are way easier. I want to know why it does not work with whereRaw() the way I use it. The reason why I want to know this is because I need it to work like that in other functions.This is merely for testing purpose because this query is quite simple.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Laravel query builder which puts your input as it is in the SQL query's where clause. Think of it as the where() function whose input argument will not be processed before inserting into queries. WhereRaw: Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query

Comment: If you visit Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder you would find method This might help you
`public function whereRaw($sql, array $bindings = [], $boolean = 'and')
    {
        $type = 'raw';

        $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'sql', 'boolean');

        $this->addBinding($bindings, 'where');

        return $this;
    }`

Comment: Already checked it, can't seem to spot the issue. Like I said, the constructed query is 100% correct but for some reason something goes wrong behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'name != Ford';
$brands = DB::table('ni_carbrands')
                ->whereRaw(':name',['name'=>$name])
                ->select('id','name')
                ->get();
```

this is equivalent query

```
select from ni_carbrands where 'name != Ford'
```

of course it doesn't work, because you have so

```
select from ni_carbrands where name != Ford
```

problem in quotes